# JSTL format Date error for 00:00:00.0 date type

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, date, jstl

I use this as format:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${rule.startDate}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
```

`startDate` is `java.util.Date` and it get form Sybase by hibernate.

I am sure the `fmt` is available in the page. I can format Number type data, but I use this format for the Date. it always give me format error:

```
Unparseable date: "2013-03-01 00:00:00.0"
```

I am not sure this `00:00:00.0` causes the issue, but I can use the format by Java:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
 ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
 System.out.println(formatter.format(rule.getStartDate()));
```

It is so dispirited.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Are you passing the date as a string?

Comment: Could you post the `rule` class?

Comment: the date is a Date type. didn't do any change.

Comment: sure post the rule  i can use its other filed